# Pausing, resuming and resetting steps counting in iOS Core Motion

Tags: ios, xcode, core-motion

I am writing an iOS app where it counts the steps taken by the user when activated using a button. I am able to count the steps now, but I would like to be able to pause and reset the steps counter by user request. I am not that experienced with XCode, so there might be an easy way to do it. I used a code similar to one available on Stackoverflow:

```html
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DTStepModelController.h"
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stepsCountingLabel;  @property (nonatomic, strong) CMStepCounter *cmStepCounter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;


@end

@implementation ViewController
{
   DTStepModelController *_stepModel;
}


- (NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue
{
    if (_operationQueue == nil)
    {
        _operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    }
    return _operationQueue;
}

- (void)updateStepCounterLabelWithStepCounter:(NSInteger)countedSteps
{
    self.stepsCountingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)countedSteps];
}

- (IBAction)StartCountingSteps:(id)sender {
    if ([CMStepCounter isStepCountingAvailable])
    {
        self.cmStepCounter = [[CMStepCounter alloc] init];
        [self.cmStepCounter startStepCountingUpdatesToQueue:self.operationQueue updateOn:1 withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSDate *timestamp, NSError *error)
         {
             [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                 [self updateStepCounterLabelWithStepCounter:numberOfSteps];
             }];
         }];
    }

}
```

Any insight, or suggessions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer for my question. Please note that my answer and the previous code in the question will not work if you're using iOS 8.2 or above as Apple discontinue supporting steps counting. In the new iOS version, you can query the M7 counter and save the value, store it, then subtract the new value from the old one.

Anyway, for the above code, you can stop the counter (PauseCounter method) but it will reset the counter to zero.

```js
-(IBAction) PauseCounting: (id) sender {
  [self.cmStepCounter stopStepCountingUpdates];
} - (IBAction) ResumeCounting: (id) sender {
  [self.cmStepCounter startStepCountingUpdatesToQueue: self.operationQueue updateOn: 1 withHandler: ^ (NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSDate * timestamp, NSError * error) {
    [
      [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
        [self updateStepCounterLabelWithStepCounter: numberOfSteps];
      }
    ];
  }];

}
```